# jquery mobile ajax does not apply css

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-post

Im trying to create a scroll down ajax everything works fine but the css doesn't apply to the new content. Here what I have. Is their anyway to fix it. What makes it for jquery mobile ajax to lose its css.

```
<style>
    #vart{ 
       height:170pt;width:200pt; 
       margin:2pt; float:left; 
       text-align:center; color:#666
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    function last_msg_funtion()
    {
         var ID=$(".images:last").attr("id");
         $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">');

         $.post("load/load.php?lastid="+ID,
             function(data){
                 if (data != "") {
                      $(".images:last").after(data);
                 }
                 $('div#last_msg_loader').trigger("pagecreate").trigger("refresh");
             }
         );
    };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            last_msg_funtion();
        }
    });

});

</script>

<div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
```

Comment: Try `.on('pagebeforeshow', function ()` instead of `.ready()`

Comment: i try it but its showing a error on firebug for firefox